# Checkbox Custom HTML Attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Really odd issue going on here.

Rendering a regular Checkbox using the build in HTML Helper method and adding two attributes;

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Prompt.PromptChoices.Choices[i].cbSelected, new { @class = Model.Prompt.Name + " required", fid = Model.Prompt.PromptChoices.Choices[i].FollowUpPromptID.ToString() })
```

Here is the markup that is generated:

```
<input id="DepartmentSections_3__DepartmentSectionSubSection_2__DepartmentSubSectionPrompts_1__Prompt_Answer" name="DepartmentSections[3].DepartmentSectionSubSection[2].DepartmentSubSectionPrompts[1].Prompt.Answer" type="radio" value="{ fid = 19, data_val = true }">
```

The problem is the 'Value' attribute is where my two custom attributes are going. Does anyone know why?

Not posting the Model as I dont think its relivant to the question, but if you need anymore information, please let me know.

Ive tried passing the ID as an int and string w/ no change. 
Ive tried changing the ordering of the attributes. 
Ive tried just removing the concating of data_Val just for testing..nothing

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

*EDIT: Using MVC 5

Comment: You expect "fid" to be an attribute? if so, you should use "data_fid" instead

Comment: I tried that and it does the same thing except the name is now 'data_fid' inside the value attribute.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you override CheckBoxFor somewhere?  I find it strange as well, even stranger that your @class name doesn't come through in the class="" list in the markup.  It is also omitted from your value="" even though fid is in there.  Also, why it is a type="radio" when you are doing a CheckBoxFor?

Comment: @Adam No i didnt. I actually checked the same thing just in case lol. Good catch on the radio...lemme see